# Problem when trying to calculate the median using R

Tags: r

I know there is a build-in function in R that calculates the median, but I was asked to make a function myself, which I have some problems with. This is what I have come up with:

```
My.median<-function(X){

  n<-X[order(X)]        #in order to make the list ordered

  if (length(n)%%2 == 0){  #if even number I want R to take the two numbers in the middle and divide

    median_X= (X[(length(n)-1)/2] + (X[length(n)/2]))/2

  }else{

    median_X=X[length(n)/2]

  }

  print(median_X)

}
```

The function works fine, when the list has an uneven number, but doesn't work properly when the list has an even number. Can anybody see the problem or give me a tip please?

Comment: You create `n` (ordered `X`), but use it only for `length`

Comment: Try `(n[(length(n) / 2 + 1)] + n[length(n) / 2]) / 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
My.median<-function(X){

  n<-X[order(X)]        #in order to make the list ordered

  if (length(n)%%2 == 0){  #if neven number I want R to take the two numbers in the middle and divide

    median_X= (n[length(n)/2] + n[length(n)/2+1])/2

  }else{

    median_X=n[(length(n)+1)/2]

  }

  median_X

}
```

You had two initial errors:

1. Creating the sorted vector `n` but then subsetting from `X` instead of `n`.
2. The indices for subsetting from the sorted vector were one too low.